# TStringGrid and Insert key

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++builder

I'm working on a problem in C++Builder.  I have to create a task management software for a company, but I am having trouble with some concepts.  My first problem is a simple one, but I don't see the error.

On my form, I have a `TrStringGrid`, which is a modified `TStringGrid`, and I want that each time the user clicks on the <kbd>insert</kbd> key on the keyboard, a new row is filled in automatically.

The app starts with a `TStringGrid` with 2 rows, one is fixed and can't be modified and the second one is empty.

This is what it looks like:

[image: Grid]

The first time the user presses the <kbd>insert</kbd> key, I want the second row (the row that is not grey) to be filled in.  The second and subsequent times the user presses the <kbd>insert</kbd> key, a new row should be added and filled in automatically.

I can't get it to work, and I don't know if I'm doing it the right way or not.

```
//method called each time a key is pressed 
void __fastcall TForm1::rStringGridEd1KeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    int counter = 1;
    switch(Key)
    {
        case VK_INSERT: //VK_INSERT for the insert button
            if(counter < 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0;i< rStringGridEd1->RowCount; i++) {
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[0][i] = "a";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[1][i] = "b";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[2][i] = "c";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[3][i] = "d";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[4][i] = "e";
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if(counter >= 2){
                for (int i = 0;i< rStringGridEd1->RowCount; i++) {
                    rStringGridEd1->RowCount++; // this is used to add a row
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[0][i] = "a";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[1][i] = "b";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[2][i] = "c";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[3][i] = "d";
                    rStringGridEd1->Cells[4][i] = "e";
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in the `calulatenewdate` function you don't need the variable `tmp`. Since you pass `data` by value all modifications to it will be done on the local variable inside the function.

Comment: Hi, I would recommend to split these 3 problems into 3 questions, if possible.

Comment: Ok i will do it, i thought it would be easier this

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code.  Using a local variable for your row counter.  Using loops when you should not be.  Incrementing the `RowCount` property incorrectly.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int counter = 0;

void __fastcall TForm1::rStringGridEd1KeyDown(TObject *Sender, WORD &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    if (Key == VK_INSERT)
    {
        if (counter > 0)
            rStringGridEd1->RowCount = rStringGridEd1->RowCount + 1;

        int row = rStringGridEd1->FixedRows + counter;

        rStringGridEd1->Cells[0][row] = "a";
        rStringGridEd1->Cells[1][row] = "b";
        rStringGridEd1->Cells[2][row] = "c";
        rStringGridEd1->Cells[3][row] = "d";
        rStringGridEd1->Cells[4][row] = "e";

        ++counter;
    }
}
```

Personally, I don't like `TStringGrid` very much. It is ugly, difficult to work with, and manages memory inefficiently. I prefer to use `TListView` in vsReport mode instead, and usually in virtual mode.  You might consider doing the same.